# What is misogi?

Tags: aikido

I have heard the word Misogi (禊) during Aikido, and read it on books.

Says that aikido is one thing, but also that misogi is the "extra training" in order to make aikido really works in a real battle / real life. I have seen that it also translates as purification.

My question is, what actually is this? Are there techniques that this can be done, and what is the actual effect on the person ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misogi

Comment: It would help some for answering if I knew a little more about the context you have heard it in with reference to Aikido.  _Misogi_ is more of a shinto concept.

Comment: @DavidH.Clements I have here that on aikido, this is not mean that is aikido only. Here is a book for example that I read it http://www.amazon.com/Secrets-Aikido-John-Stevens/dp/1570622353/  search on look inside to see the pages

Comment: Misogi refers to ritual cleansing by water. I think someone might be telling you to take a shower after practice ;) I don't know much about Aikido, but I do know that we were Taught Tae Kyu as part of our Taekwondo training. Tae Kyu is supposedly top secret deadly stuff, but it basically boiled down to "if a guy grabs your arm, poke him in the eye or kick him in the nuts until he lets go". Don't expect Misogi to be any different.

Comment: @JuannStrauss If I do not know something, I do not expect anything, neither imaging anything. I just do not know it.

Comment: I am just saying that it's probably going to be much more boring than it sounds.

Comment: @JuannStrauss If I do not know "Joann Strauss", and never talk with him/her, how can I say if its an interesting person, or a boring one ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What is misogi?

*Misogi* is any of a number of purification rituals found in *shinto*, the most common of which is *misogi shuho* or *misogi-no-gawa*, a purification ritual of cleansing the body in a river.

To be somewhat precise, the *kami* ("spirit-god" for lack of a better description) who created the Solar System and the ancestor of all *kami* on Earth, Izanagi-no-Okami) visited *yomi* (the world of the dead) and, upon emerging, performed the first *misogi shuho* to cleanse his body of the defilement of that world. In doing so, he first cast all his belongings into the river, then himself, and from all his belongings, from his eyes, and from his nose, came the other *kami*. (I am, of course, overly simplifying this because I doubt you care which *kami* sprung from which orifice).

This *misogi shuho* has 6 elements:

1. To purify yourself from attachments
2. Self reflection
3. To find the middle way
4. To check constantly and correct thoroughly
5. Inner willingness and sincere effort
6. Completeness

Another ritual common among *aikidoka* is something called *misogi-no-kokyu-ho* or purification of spiritual refinement. This is an arduous form of directed meditation, restricted diet, and imposed asceticism, the first experience of which is four days long.

> Are there techniques that this can be done[?]

Yes. It's an extremely *shinto* concept, and *Ueshiba Morihei* was part of a *shinto* cult called *Omoto-kyo* (I use the term "cult" to imply a non-mainstream religious sect, not to imply anything else – some people get touchy about this word).

In the four day *shogaku shugyo* of *misogi-no-kokyu-ho*, the student wears *gi* and *hakama*; eat 3 meals a day consisting of a barley-rice mixture, soybean paste, salted plum (*umeboshi*), and radish pickles (*takuan*); and sleep on *tatami* mats. For those four days, the students sit in *seiza*, practice breathing techniques, and chant from their *hara* (abdomen). This is an intensive; a practice of deep commitment to push the aspirant hard.

In the *misogi-no-gawa*, the aspirants strip down to *fundoshi* (loincloth) and *hachimaki* (headband), and sit in meditation for a time. Then they are led through a river to a waterfall, where they stand in meditation and self-reflection, performing a chant (*misagi- no-Oharai*) under a waterfall.

> [W]hat is the actual effect on the person?

These are rituals, and, like all rituals, the **actual** effects will vary from person to person based on the meaning they ascribe to them. *Ueshiba Morihei*'s epiphanies at different times in his life were an understanding of his martial art as an expression of his spiritual beliefs.

If you ascribe no personal beliefs to the practices, they will be shallow, rote motions and have no gain. In this case, the best one can hope for is a capacity to sit in *seiza* and breathe, or, in the case of *misogi shuho*, a resistance to icy cold water.

However, if you take the time to ascribe a belief to what you will get out of something, and that belief is reasonable ("I will emerge with a cleared perspective of the world," not "I'm going to come out of the water to find $50 on the ground."), it will have that effect ***upon you***.

Comment: Now I have 6 more questions for the 6 elements :) - this midle way called "αρετή" in greece, and actually there is not correct world in other languages. Socrates search for the meaning of this word but never say clear what it is.

Comment: Can I ask you something simple: do you have practice misogi ?

Comment: I have not practiced it. I know of it because I study Japanese martial arts, and the subjects that touch on them, *Shinto* being one. I do not believe in ritual purification, but understand the psychology behind such actions.

Comment: is phyhology or body purification/exercise ?

Comment: There's no difference between ritual purification's effect and its underlying psychological cause. αρετή (Arete in English) is not the middle way so much... Arete carries almost a connotation of being excellent, or above things. The middle way is more taking the path of least resistance. When Izanagi-no-Kami moved into the river, he chose a part neither too swift nor too sluggish. This would be finding harmony.

Answer (score 4):

In the aikido context, misogi is usually used to refer to activities aimed at spiritual purification. For instance, if you end your training session with a breathing exercise in seiza, that is probably misogi... you're settling your mind, body and spirit, drawing in fresh air and exhaling impurity.

However, like a lot of aikido practice, misogi exercises are used in order to show you a more general principle, and give you the opportunity to embody it: misogi is a state of mind, not a set of breathing exercises (or taki gyo, or whatever).

Sugano Shihan described misogi as "a constant process of removing the obstacles to sincere practice".

And O Sensei is quoted as saying: "All aikido movement is misogi".

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

I’ve been introduced to misogi at my dojo during the first classes I ever took. We practise misogi at the beginning of each class. We sit down or stand during this exercise. Sensei recommends us to close our eyes. Everyone becomes silent and still. We take a few minites to breath deeply.

On my first class I was guided during our misogi exercise. I was told to allow the day to pass and leave the weight of my day off the mat. I was told to empty my head, release my thoughts and create an open space for the very fast paced, rewarding and demanding practiss we are about to undertake. Full focus is achieved by this exercise.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I strongly urge you to check out the [help] to learn how we work. This, while a nice personal story, does not really answer the question.

Comment: Thank you for this comments - I have travel some times around the world for seminars for misogi - just to see/take a taste of what they do. So even that is helpful.